# npm facebook-chat-api error

Tags: jquery, node.js, facebook

I´m getting problems with this method. The console response with There was a temporary error , try again.

Error:

## 1545012

transientError:

## 1

I´m doing something wrong, this is the link for the npm facebook-chat-api
https://www.npmjs.com/package/facebook-chat-api

```
 //HTML
    
  <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="type your email"></input>
  <label for="pwd">Type your pass: </label>
  <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="type your password"></input>
  <input type="button" id="login" value="Send"></input>



 //JS
    $('#login').on('click', function(){
                $.post("/login",
                        {
                            user : $('#user').val(),
                            pwd  : $('#pwd').val()
                        });
            });

//Node
    app.post('/login', function(req, response) {
        var user_id = req.body.user;
        var pwd = req.body.pwd;
        var threadID = "";
        var userID = 'xxxxxxxx';
        var msq = req.body.msg;
    
        login({ email: user_id, password: pwd }, function callback (err, api) {
            if(err) return console.error(err);
         
            api.listen(function callback(err, message) {
                threadID = message.threadID;
                api.sendMessage(message.body, message.threadID);
            });
    
            api_obj = api;
    
            api.addUserToGroup(userID, threadID, function callback (err, api) {
                if(err) return console.error(err);
            });

        })
    
    });
```

Comment: If it is not using the API it must be using something that isn't supported by Facebook so I would expect it to break all the time

Comment: _“As of right now, the only way to automate the chat functionalities is to emulate the browser”_ – that is not allowed; go read Facebook’s ToS.